# uploading a file and then copying it to two differnt directories?

Tags: php, file, upload, move

i know this is a very basic question and i know i have done it before its just htta i cant seem to track the code or get the answer on the web... let me explain...

i am uploading a image

i want the original image in one dir and i want to create a thumbnail and tore that in another dir....i plan on using class.upload (verot.net)

i wanted to know if i can move_uploaded_file twice if not how do i do it..

Comment: Have you tried it?  Why don't you *try* the approach you have outlined?  If you encounter problems *then* come back and ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, firstly use `move_uploaded_file($tmp, $dest)` and secondly `copy($dest, $dest2)`

Btw, your class should be able to save thumbnail by any path, different from the source image.

/me to the rescue ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a copy of a file in a new location, use the `copy()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

This won't do anything to create a thumbnail, though; this will just duplicate the same file in two places. To create a thumbnail, you may consider using PHP's GD image processing functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php